# Getting JSON file from Google Places API

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp, google-places-api

I am trying to use the Places API and I was initially trying to use $.ajax from jQuery but I kept getting an unexpected token error on the first element of the file. But I realized then that you can't get JSONP from the Places API. So below is a sample of what it returns, I can't for the life of me get it to print id into console (for starters)...Could someone maybe point me in the right direction?

JSON returned from Places:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 33.7862590,
               "lng" : -117.8531270
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "5be9a13a28635cf8fd2ef3c62c24d51277a4ba58",
         "name" : "Kimmies Coffee Cup",
         "rating" : 3.30,
         "reference" : "CnRpAAAANKLoOHJ1STFaFavIPjm2bpMDneGTv0AXfixyl-koF7KSK-lQSldk3c01RFJu9Gf62zXnRScte-dkPCBU8KuxCo7AMctfuaIhNkPE8RKENF9HeMlkuEg-Scp97--1VWJvjpNQjc6xRvdXsbf7V8NrSRIQnXjZBKbrSeSg2sTwBosKghoUEFlNDIN5cnVbn5n7aNtwycord-E",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "190 S Glassell St # B, Orange"
      }
      ]
}
```

And this is what I was trying but obviously I can't use it anymore...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        location: '33.787794,-117.853111',
        radius: 100,
        name: 'coffee',
        key: 'KEY_HERE',
        sensor: false,
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.results[0].id);
    }
  });
});
```

Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a parseJSON method which will create a javascript object from JSON.

Once you have this object then

obj.results will return you the results array.

results[0].id will give you the id of the first result.

Comment: I saw that, I wasn't sure if it applied to my situation...good to know it does! I'm not entirely sure how to add the data (ie location, radius, name, key, sensor) to that function. Where does that part go? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the result when you use datatype json instead of jsonp?

Comment: It gives me: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.787794%2C-117.853111&radius=100&name=coffee&key=MY_KEY&sensor=false. Origin http://website.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop just to print the id. You can remove it and then try. Also, not sure what's 'myResult'. It doesn't appear to be defined anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I copy pasted a function I had half changed...myResult is supposed to be the parameter passed in, I'll edit my post. And I get the same result without the loop, I just replaced the things I was doing in the loop (generating a table) with the console.log command to simplify it and isolate the problem.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a JS debugger to see exactly what you are getting as 'data' in the success function, and then access the data accordingly.

Comment: I've never really used a JS debugger, do you recommend one for Chrome?

Comment: Chrome has a built in debugger. Just press F12.